# Click TextBox Open FileDialog - On run time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a form to generate 3 groups of textboxes at run time. I'm trying to achieve this: when the user click a textbox of the group "txtboxe", a FileDialog opens so the user can choose the file. When the file is picked, i wwant to get the filepath.

The problem is, usually, i would use a sub like - textboxe_Click - but i need this to work inside a existing module, and the name of each textbox is generate at run time.

So... Any ideas? I tried to use multiple times something with 'Controls' commands, but without any sucess. I manage to pick the data from each textbox, but not to control a click or change on a textbox group.

I'm providing the code below.

`````
Dim i As Long
Dim o As Long


Dim number As Long

number = InputBox("How many docs?", "Number of docs")


Dim txtB1 As Control
Dim txtB2 As Control

For i = 1 To number
    Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
    With txtB1
    .Name = "txtbox" & i
    .Height = 16
    .Width = 30
    .Left = 60
    .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
    .Value = i
    .Locked = True
    .BackColor = &H80000000
    End With
    
    Set txtB2 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
    With txtB2
    .Name = "txtboxw" & i
    .Height = 18
    .Width = 234
    .Left = 162
    .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
    Debug.Print .Name
    End With

 Set txtB3 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
    With txtB3
    .Name = "txtboxe" & i
    .Height = 18
    .Width = 264
    .Left = 420
    .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
    Debug.Print .Name
    End With

Next i

    

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim p As Long
For p = 1 To number

cells(p + 1, 1) = Controls("txtbox" & p).Value
cells(p + 1, 2) = Controls("txtboxw" & p).Value
cells(p + 1, 3) = Controls("txtboxe" & p).Value

Next p


End Sub ````
`````

Comment: Are these textboxes added to a userform or a worksheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering event handlers with dynamically created controls is tricky.

But you can do it using a Class Module and `WithEvent` variable.

First, add the following code as a Class Module `ControlEvent`.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents targetCtrl As MSForms.TextBox
 
Public Sub SetCtrl(new_ctrl As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set targetCtrl = new_ctrl
End Sub

' You can add arbitrary event handlers for TextBox as ``targetCtrl_(Event handler name)``
Private Sub targetCtrl_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        If .Show() Then
            ' You can access the control with the targetCtrl class variable
            targetCtrl.Value = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then, modify your code in the UserForm to the following.

I added an array `ctrls` to store the `ControlEvent` class instances and set the created controls to the `WithEvents` class variables with `SetCtrl` method.

```
Private ctrls As Variant    ' Added

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim o As Long


    Dim number As Long

    number = InputBox("How many docs?", "Number of docs")
    
    Dim txtB1 As Control
    Dim txtB2 As Control
    Dim txtB3 As Control
    
    ReDim ctrls(0 To number - 1)
    
    For i = 1 To number
        Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
        With txtB1
        .Name = "txtbox" & i
        .Height = 16
        .Width = 30
        .Left = 60
        .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
        .Value = i
        .Locked = True
        .BackColor = &H80000000
        End With
        
        Set txtB2 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
        With txtB2
        .Name = "txtboxw" & i
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 234
        .Left = 162
        .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
        Debug.Print .Name
        End With
    
        Set txtB3 = Controls.Add("Forms.Textbox.1")
        With txtB3
        .Name = "txtboxe" & i
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 264
        .Left = 420
        .Top = 20 + (i * 40)
        Debug.Print .Name
        End With
    
        Set ctrls(i - 1) = New ControlEvent  ' Added
        ctrls(i - 1).SetCtrl txtB3           ' Added
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Man, **U DID IT!**. I`m having trouble with this code since forever!  Thank`s a lot, i`ll study more about class module and contorl events.